# AWK script shebang to allow dash-prefixed arguments

Tags: shell, awk, sh, posix

I wanted to write a fairly complex AWK script, which would take a bunch of command-line arguments, parse them and then perform some work.

Unfortunately I ran into trouble trying to pass dash-prefixed (`-arg`) arguments to the script, as they are being interpreted by AWK instead.

```
$ ./script.awk -arg
awk: not an option: -arg
```

I noticed the `--` option, but I am unsure how to use it in the shebang meaningfully. I was unable to find any way to get the name of the file and reference it in the script's shebang (something like `#!/usr/bin/awk -f $FILE --`).

Then I thought maybe the `-W exec` option could be used to solve the issue, but I keep getting the following error (even without attempting to use the `--` option with it), which seems to suggest that the name of the file is not even really being appended to the end of the shebang command.

```
$ ./script.awk
awk: vacuous option: -W  exec
awk: 1: unexpected character '.'
```

**Is there a way to make a standalone (single file, no wrapper script) executable AWK script, which can accept dash-prefixed arguments?**

---

Why am I trying to abuse AWK to this extent? Mostly out of curiosity, but also to get rid of the wrapper shell script, which I currently have to use just to execute the AWK script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
awk -f script.awk -- "$@"
```

The solution should be POSIX-compliant (assuming AWK's path is `/usr/bin/awk`). Even if you have a non-POSIX-compliant solution, please share it as well.

Comment: Probably not possible without a shell script wrapper. Read your `execve(2)` man page

Comment: @glennjackman That's what I assumed at first, but then I remembered that there's typically a hacky solution to everything in shell / -nix. And thankfully, there truly seems to be a way to achieve this (see below).

Comment: If you create a [mcve] we can show you how to best implement it.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm not really sure what you mean in this case. I've given an example of what an argument passed to the script may look like, but the rest would be just a generic AWK script (most of which hasn't even been written yet, because this was one of the first issues I started dealing with). I need to have all the standard AWK functionality.

Comment: I mean show us something concrete that you're trying to do - provide concise, testable sample input, expected output, and a simple script you want to execute and how you want to be able to call it.

Comment: @EdMorton It's a generic question and everyone knows what AWK code looks like and how it's executed. I want the solution to work for any AWK code, therefore an example would defeat the whole purpose. A rough example of calling the script has been provided. The intended result is for the AWK script to behave just like a shell script would (take any number arguments in any format, don't print anything unintentionally and possibly exit with a specified exit code).

Comment: OK, apparently it's just me who doesn't understand awk well enough to grasp the problem you're trying to solve. Good luck.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm sorry, but having a long (>200 lines) AWK script inside of a shell script (even worse, wrapped in single quotes instead of a here-doc) doesn't really solve the problem I had in mind. AWK scripts can be execute as standalone, they just cannot accept `-`-prefixed arguments because those are handled by the `awk` interpreter. And that's the issue I want to solve.

Comment: I'm not seeing what difference it would make if your shell script is 200 lines of awk code under a `#!/bin/awk` shebang or 200 lines of awk wrapped in `awk '...'`. It's the same 200 lines of awk code either way.

Comment: @natiiix, you probably want to read https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getopt-Function.html

Comment: @EdMorton I've explained it at least twice already to you. If I do that, I lose the ability to use syntax highlighting, plus with your solution specifically I can't even use single quotes in the AWK code. I'm not sure about the command length limit either, it could apply here and cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: @glennjackman I don't really see how that's related to my question. To me that just seems like the explanation of `getopt()` function implemented in AWK. I'm not sure if it's GAWK-specific, but even if not, this only works for single-character options (which isn't really the case with `-arg`). More importantly, it appears to require the `--` sequence to work. And most importantly, I have an argument parser written in AWK already, that's not the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

**Understanding the problem:**

As far as I understand, the OP has a complex script called `script.awk`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{print "ARGC", ARGC; for(i=0;i<ARGC;++i) print "ARG"i,ARGV[i]}
```

which the OP would like to call using various traditional POSIX-style one letter options,  or GNU-style long options. POSIX options start with a single <hyphen>-character (`-`)  while long options start with a two <hyphen>-characters (`--`). This, however, fails as awk is interpreting these arguments to be passed on to awk itself and not to the scripts argument list. Eg.

```
$ ./script.awk
ARGC 1
ARG0 awk
$ ./script.awk -arg
awk: not an option: -arg
```

> ***Question:** Is there a way to write a POSIX compliant script which can handle such hyphenated arguments? (Suggestions are made in the original question.)*

**Observation 1:** While not immediately clear, it must be mentioned that the error message is generated by **mawk** and not the more common GNU version **gawk**. Where mawk fails, gawk does not:

```
$ mawk -f script.awk -arg
mawk: not an option -arg
$ gawk -f script.awk -arg
ARGC 2
ARG0 gawk
ARG1 -arg
```

Nonetheless, it must be mentioned that for both gawk and mawk, different behavriour can be observed when the arguments clash with the optional arguments of awk. Example:

```
$ mawk -f script.awk -var   # this fails as gawk expects -v ar=foo
mawk: improper assignment: -v ar
$ gawk -f script.awk -var   # this fails as gawk expects -v ar=foo
gawk: `oo' argument to `-v' not in `var=value' form
$ gawk -f script.awk -var=1 # this works and creates variable ar
$ mawk -f script.awk -var=1 # this works and creates variable ar
$ mawk -f script.awk -foo  # this fails as it expects a file oo
mawk: cannot open oo (No such file or directory)
$ gawk -f script.awk -foo  # this fails as it expects a file oo
gawk: fatal: can't open source file `oo' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

**Observation 2:** The OP suggests the usage of a double-<hyphen> to indicate that the consecutive options are only part of awk. This, however, is an extension of both mawk and gawk and not part of the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).

> **`--`**:  indicates the unambiguous end of options. **<sup>source: `man mawk`</sup>**
>   **`--`**:  Signal the end of options. This is useful to allow further arguments to the AWK  program itself to start with a `-`.  This provides consistency with the argument parsing convention used by most other POSIX programs. **<sup>source: `man gawk`</sup>**

Furthermore, the usage of the double-hyphen assumes that all arguments after `--` are files:

```
$ ./script.awk -- -arg1 file
ARGC 3
ARG0 mawk
ARG1 -arg1
ARG2 file
mawk: cannot open -arg1 (No such file or directory)
```

**Suggestion 1:** While the concept of flags are a nice-to-have, you might consider making use of the standard [POSIX compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) assignment as arguments:

```
$ ./script.awk arg1=1 arg2=1 arg3=1 file
```

However, the downside of this is that these assignments are only processed after the `BEGIN` block is executed. (cfr. [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html))

**Suggestion 2:** a simple improvement would be to make use of `ARGV` and `ARGC` and use hyphen-less arguments. This is a bit more BSD-like (cfr `ps aux`), and could look like:

```
$ ./script.awk arg1 arg2 arg3
ARGC 4
ARG0 gawk
ARG1 arg1
ARG2 arg2
ARG3 arg3
```

**Suggestion 3:** If none of the above options are up to your liking, you have to consider using a hybrid between `sh` and `awk`. The word hybrid implies we write syntax that is recognized by both `sh` and `awk`. An awk program is composed of pairs of the form:

```
pattern { action }
```

where `pattern` can be ignored. This resembles closely the compound command syntax of `sh`:

```
{ compound-list ; }
```

This allows us now to write the following shell script `script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
{ "awk" "-f" "$0" "--" "${@}" ; "exit" ;}
# your awk script comes here
```

By writing it this way, `awk` will interpret the first action as nothing more than a concatenation of strings. `sh` on the other hand will execute it nominally.

Sadly, while it looks promising, this does **NOT** work due to the effect of the double hyphen.

```
$ ./script.sh file   # this works
ARGC 2
ARG0 awk
ARG1 file

$ ./script.sh -arg file   # this does not work
ARGC 3
ARG0 mawk
ARG1 -arg1
ARG2 file
mawk: cannot open -arg1 (No such file or directory)
```

An ugly solution could be by starting to parse the script itself in itself to remove the first two lines before passing it back to awk. But this will only solve the problem for scripts only having a BEGIN block.

Comment: For me, this solution prints `Hangup` at the end of the script's execution (could be WSL Debian's `sh` quirk to report SIGHUP). It seems to me that replacing the `kill` command with plain old `exit` solves that. Am I missing something? Also, I believe you've omitted the key part required for dash-prefixed arguments to work (the AWK call should be `awk -f "$0" "--" "$@"` unless I'm mistaken).

Comment: As far as I can tell `{ awk -f "$0" "--" "$@"; exit; }` works just fine. Thanks a ton, this is a brilliant solution! Please edit your answer to contain the full solution to the question, so that I can accept it.

Comment: You cannot use the exit statement as Awk will read the first line and immediately terminate due to the exit and then process the END statement.

Comment: You are right, good point. The files passed to the script are indeed not processed. However both `BEGIN` and `END` are executed, which is good enough for me. I didn't realize because my `BEGIN` rule ends with `exit` anyways. Still, you might want to add the missing `"--"` to the `awk` call in your answer because the current code behaves much like regular `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`.

Comment: I don't have the faintest idea why you'd do this instead of just putting `awk 'script' "$@"` in the file. Can anyone explain what the problem is we're trying to solve and how this solves it?

Comment: @EdMorton I must have all the code in a single executable file. If I pass the code to `awk` from a shell script, I will have to have two copies of the code in order to get AWK syntax highlighting (AWK code inside of a shell string isn't typically highlighted properly). This makes it extremely easy to make a mistake when copying the code or to forget to sync any changes, basically a DRY violation.

Comment: So the problem we're trying to solve is that the editor you use doesn't highlight awk syntax correctly when the awk code is in a single quoted string?

Comment: you can remove the `kill` line by using `{ exec awk ...` that will *replace* the shell process

Comment: Adding the `--` gives me a syntax error, equivalent to this awk error: `awk 'BEGIN { 0 -- ""}'`, but I found a workaround: quote everything `{ "exec" "awk" "-f" "$0" "--" "$@"; }`

Comment: @EdMorton This has nothing to do with *my* editor. It's a general problem with any editor. Having the AWK code inside of another language's code is simply inconvenient, impractical and an awful practice, which could easily lead to tons of unforeseen problems. I'm looking for a solution to a specific problem. If I wanted to embed my AWK code into a shell code, I could have done that easily, but I wanted to execute the AWK code without having to worry it's gonna be unexpectedly manipulated by another program.

Comment: @glennjackman Makes sense since `--` is AWK's decrement operator, but I've already put it into quotes in my first comment. However, the first note about `exec` is very interesting. It indeed seems to do the trick without having to use `kill` or `exit`. By the way, as far as quotation marks go, `{ exec awk -f "$0" "--" "$@"; }` should be enough for as long as `exec`, `awk` and `f` aren't defined within the AWK script (which should be easy to avoid). Thanks for that note.

Comment: @natiiix I have massively updated the answer coming to the conclusion that it does not really work.

Comment: @kvantour Do you delete the `ARGV`s? Because it works fine for me when I do.

Comment: @glennjackman The double hyphen method seems to expect that all arguments after are files. So if you have a `-- -arg` in it, it will try to process the file `-arg` for the first action pattern pair. Since this file does not exist, awk will actually crash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190400/discussion-between-natiiix-and-kvantour).

Comment: @kvantour your answer looks thorough but I simply don't use shebangs to execute awk scripts within shell scripts for the reasons I've stated previously so there's probably others with more experience doing that who could provide better feedback.